# Pinging NGINX with virtual hosts returns the wrong domain name

Tags: domain-name-system, reverse-dns

Just as the title says - I'd like to know how to specify either:

1. How to return the domain that is pinged (e.g. if I ping "test.com" I get something like "64 bytes from test.com...", or same for whatever domain I ping.
2. One domain that I specify, instead of a seemingly random one.

I've tried using a default_server directive, but it doesn't help with this case.

Answer (score 2):

ping uses ICMP protocol to send echo requests / responses over the internet. It has nothing to do with HTTP or web servers.

Ping displays the reverse DNS entry for the IP address. Reverse DNS entries are configured by the entity that owns the IP address block.

Often hosting services have an option to configure the reverse DNS name for your VPS.

You need to check with your service provider how to configure the reverse DNS record.